# Run php snippet in interval

Tags: javascript, php, html, chat

I'm currently making a hacky way for a chat application, just to play around really.

What happens is, you allow an user to login, or register, and they will be send to the index.php which is a chatbox.

Once you send a message, this message is stored inside the database. The html then loads in the messages with php using a foreach loop.

So now, once I send a message, I use AJAX to send this message to a php file, which processes it and sends it to the database. I'm now trying to figure out how I can allow the following code snippet to run in an interval, so that it will fill the contents of the chat from the database by 'x' seconds.

```js
sendbutton.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var message = sendinput.val();

        var data = {
            message: message
        };

        if(message != ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                url: 'sendmessage.php',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == "True"){
                        sendinput.val('');

                        // Could do an ajax get request here.
                    }
                },
                
            })
        }
    });
```

```html
<?php 
        $messages = Database::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY createdAt ASC');

        foreach($messages->results() as $message){
        $owner = Database::getInstance()->get('user', array('ID', '=', $message->ID));
        
        $ownername = $owner->first()->username;

        $toDrop = <<<ETO
        <div class="message">
            <div class="message-name">
                <p>$ownername</p>
            </div>
            <div class="message-content">
                <p>$message->message</p>
                <p class="message-time">$message->createdAt</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
ETO;

            print $toDrop;
        }
        
        
?>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

You can not run this snippet, but I do think this gives a general idea on what I'm achieving or trying to achieve.

Comment: jQuery has `$.post()` and `$(container).load()`, which would shorten that code considerably. As for updating the chat messages, I'd put the loading into a function, then set a timer in its success callback that calls the function again when it expires. There are better ways though, namely socket.io. Though implementing that with PHP is not as elegant as using a node.js backend.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I know, socket.io with node.js is much easier to achieve what I'm doing. But, I'm currently new to php, and I just wanted to play around. Trying to learn as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I now have a solution, which doesn't even have to get an interval, but I'm just not sure if it is the right way to go.

I made a AJAX get request which fills a div with the response from that get request.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            url: 'sendmessage.php',
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "True"){
                    sendinput.val('');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'todrop.php',
                        success: function(data){
                            $('.messages').html(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's for play and in the same time if you're gonna test it on a site with more people then it will start to kill server. 2 many connections created, so the pooling model (where you check for new msgs every x seconds or after each msg ppl sent) and db aren't that great for chat.

If you already want to do it that way I'd suggest you switch database to redis whichis much faster and you can set expiry on stored data, but in reality you'd use WebSockets or some other more real time solution.
See this https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat or just search for php/js live chat with websockets.

Comment: Honestly, all information I get is just going to be useful in the future. I will have a look at this. Thank you!